# how to use variables to read in nested json

Tags: python, json, variables, nested

I want to read in a nested json like

```
"Experiment"{
        "rats"{
            "animal":[1,2,3,4]
              }
        "dogs"{
            "animal":[1,2,3,4]
              }
            }
```

*(I hope I set all the brackets correctly)*

Now I want to make it variable to read in Dogs or rats (do not worry, I am not actually experimenting on animals :-) )

So instead of

```
conf=pd.read_json(filepath)
animal=conf[Experiment][dogs][1]
```

I would like to use

```
conf=pd.read_json(filepath)
a="dogs"
b="rats"
animal=conf[Experiment]a[1]
```

Can someone hint how to do this? Thanks

Comment: You have to quote `Experiment`, and put `a` inside `[]`: `animal=conf['Experiment'][a][1]`

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. After you load it, it's just ordinary dictionaries and lists, you access them the same way as any other dictionaries.

Comment: Of course... quite late here :-) you are the best. If you put it in an answer, I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have the answer within your question, as long as you clean up the syntax. If you change your json to this:

```
{
    "Experiment": {
        "dogs": {
            "animal": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
        },
        "rats": {
            "animal": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the comma after "dogs", surrouding `{}` and `:` to separate keys and values)
You can do it the first way with:

```
import pandas as pd

conf = pd.read_json("animals.json")
animal = conf["Experiment"]["dogs"]["animal"]
```

Or the way you wanted with:

```
import pandas as pd

a = "dogs"
conf = pd.read_json("animals.json")
animal = conf["Experiment"][a]["animal"]
```

I assumed what you're trying to grab is the array `[1,2,3,4]`, but if you want `"animal": [1,2,3,4]`, just leave off `["animal"]` from above.
Your question lacks quotes around the keys, so that was likely your issue. You can easily set a variable to be the string of the key you're looking for ("dog") and use that.
You also attempted to index `dogs` with `[1]`, but `dogs` isn't an array, so perhaps you meant to put `[]` around `"animal": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` instead of `{}`?

Also, you don't necessarily need to use `pandas` (unless you're doing a lot more other than mentioned here). You can also do it like so:

```
import json

a = "dogs"
f = open("animals.json")
conf = json.load(f)
animal = conf["Experiment"][a]["animal"]
```